# how can divide this array index into separate variables?

Tags: javascript, cordova

"Friendship SMS:$@|5825|@$:4cing.com/mobile_app/uploads/pageicon/friendship.png"

how can spilt that array[0] and store into different array

am trying to nsmaxrange

```
var subStar="|@$:";
var sub=":$@|";
```

by using that variables how can spilt that string stored that string into different variables

thanks & regards

Comment: pls look at my edited quiestion?

Comment: what's the result you are expecting after the process ? I mean what should your resulting array look like ?

Comment: Friendship SMS,5825,cing.com/mobile_app/uploads/pageicon/friendship.png like this three saparate variables

Comment: charAt()
    charCodeAt()
    concat()
    fromCharCode()
    indexOf()
    lastIndexOf()
    match()
    replace()
    search()
    slice()
    split()
    substr()
    substring()
    toLowerCase()
    toUpperCase()
    valueOf()
the above methode i need to use to solve this problem

Comment: give an example for both input and output ?

Comment: the above array[0] is Friendship SMS:$@|5825|@$:4cing.com/mobile_app/uploads/pageicon/friendship.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
var myarr = array[0].split(":");
```

then

```
myarr [0] = "Friendship SMS",
myarr [1] = "$@|5825|@$"
myarr [2] = "4cing.com/mobile_app/uploads/pageicon/friendship.png"
```

extracting one number from `myarr[1]`:

```
myarr [1] = myarr[1].match(/\d+/)[0];
```

or

```
myarr [1] = myarr[1].match(/[0-9]+/)[0];
```

then trim each array member as necessary.

Comment: If it's always a number, use a regular expression with `match()`

Comment: parseInt(/\d+/.exec("$@|5825|@$"))

Comment: alert(ids[i].parseInt(/\d+/.exec("$@|5825|@$")[i]));  not working

Comment: what do you mean by `listview`? an example please?

Answer (score 0):

```
var reg = /(.+)\:\$@\|(\d+)\|@\$\:(.+)/
var somestring = "Friendship SMS:$@|5825|@$:4cing.com/mobile_app/uploads/pageicon/friendship.png";
var youranswerarray = somestring.match(reg).slice(1);
```

You define a regular expression using subgroups to select the three portions you actually want from the text. Then you apply the match function to the string and you get an array with the matched string and the matched subgroups. You only want the subgroup so you throw away the matched string, the first element of the array, by taking a slice/copy of that array starting with the element in the 1 position.

Comment: Could you add some explanation what the code fragment is doing?